# Problems with pattern "Barrier"

Tags: algorithm, operating-system

First of all forgive my poor and very basic english.

Reading "The Little Book of Semaphores" I meet the pattern Barrier and for completeness I shortly remember here its description in [Wikipedia: pattern barrier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrier_(computer_science)) :

> *"A barrier for a group of threads or processes in the source code means any thread/process must stop at this point and cannot proceed until all other threads/processes reach this barrier."*

The author proposes the following solution for these kind of problems:

```
mutex = semaphore{1};
barrier = semaphore{0};  
count = 0;   // shared variable  
N is the number of process/thread  

(1) rendezvous();          // generic code that each process/thread must 
                           // executes before encountering the barrier  
(2) mutex.wait();  
(3) count = count + 1;
(4) mutex.signal();
(5) if (count == N)
(6)     barrier.signal();
(7) barrier.wait();
(8) barrier.signal();
  
(9) proceed_to_the_end();  // generic code that each process/thread must  
                           // executes after passing the "barrier"
```

To pratice on the problem I designed on my own the following solution:

```
mutex = semaphore{1};
barrier = semaphore{0};  
count = 0;   // shared variable  
N is the number of process/thread 

(1) rendezvous();          // generic code that each process/thread must 
                           // executes before encountering the barrier  
(2) mutex.wait();  
(3) count = count + 1;
(4) mutex.signal();
(5) if (count < N)
(6)     barrier.wait();
(7) barrier.signal();
  
(9) proceed_to_the_end();  // generic code that each process/thread must  
                           // executes after passing the "barrier"
```

I compared these 2 solutions and in my opinion they are equivalent, but this is my point of view, the result of my analysis and of course they might be wrong:
I need to compare my views.

Can you help me to find the differences (if exist)?
Can you find some subleties that differentate these 2 solutions?

Best regards and thank for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last thread to reach the barrier does an extra signal and wait in the author's version. Your version elides these, which given that the author's solution is fine, is also fine because in schedules where there are no intervening operations, the pair has no effect.

The functional difference between the versions is that yours always releases the last thread first, whereas the author's can release the threads in any order.

As a side note, if you implement this, that read of count on line 5 had better be atomic (and if you're implementing this on a processor that is not sequentially consistent, which is ~all of them at this point, then those semaphore operations had better have acquire/release memory fences).

Comment: "..that read of count on line 5 had better be atomic". Sure. TY